# TO_DATE function time zone parse error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem when trying to parse a date in Oracle:

```
TO_DATE('Fri May 16 14:30:57 EDT 2014', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY')
```

**Error:**

> ORA-01821: date format not recognized

What is wrong with the timezone?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove `DAY` from the start of your format string. Or the input must be like `Saturday May ...`.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated question, could you please giv me me suggestion one more time.

Comment: The problem lies in the TZD value. `select TO_DATE('May 16 14:30;57 2014', 'MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY') from dual;` works, while `select TO_TIMESTAMP('May 16 14:30;57 PST 2014', 'MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') from dual;` does not. Still looking for the answer...

Comment: Just a side note I guess: When converting strings with day or month names or their abbreviations then state the language used, for 'Fri' and 'May' are valid in English but not in German for instance. `TO_DATE('Fri May 16 14:30:57 EDT 2014', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('May 16 14:30;57 EDT 2014', 'MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY')
from dual;
```

Comment: The reason that `to_date` does not work seems to be that it returns a `date` value, which does not support time zones. Strange though that this is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: If you need the output as a DATE datatype, you can use CAST, as SELECT CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('May 16 14:30;57 EDT 2014', 'MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') AS DATE) from dual;

Comment: The documentation [does say](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51076) that `TZD` can only be used in a timestamp model, not a date model.